# 404 error after installing SSL certificates

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https, http-status-code-404

I recently uploaded Comodo Wildcard SSL certificates on my Bluehost hosted site.

After installation my WordPress blog is working fine ( hosted on root https://gadgetnyooz.com), but I have a few webapps in sub-domains https://applove.gadgetnyooz.com/websurf (working fine with http://) is getting redirected to WordPress 404 page.

Tried working out with WordPress `.htaccess` file but nothing happened.

Comment: Hard to speculate without seeing some configuration files. Note that the HTTPS virtual host and the HTTP virtual host do not share configuration. They are effectively separate hosts that happen to point to the same content. Ensure that you've duplicated things like DocumentRoot, DirectoryIndex, and so on to both <VirtualHost> blocks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it? because I am new to ssl //// can you give a link to some guide to make these changes??? thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, to elaborate - we need to see your configuration files before we can speculate as to what's wrong with them. Can you post your configuration files either here in your question, or on a pastebin site?

Comment: wordpress configuration file ? or php configuration file ? or any other configuration file?

Comment: Yes, those would be a good place to start. If you have other configuration files you feel would be relevant, that would help us get a better picture of what might be happening.